# sitecore : replace a part of string with empty string in xpath fast query

Tags: string, performance, xpath, replace, sitecore

I am trying to generate a report in sitecore based on username which is selected from the dropdown. I need to remove the domain part from the parameter. Is there any replace or substring kind of function available in sitecore fast query ?
i used something like Regex.Replace('{User}','domain\','') but it returns null.
Also there are methods available in Sitecore.mainutil class. How to use this class as reference in my reports.
Now the reference is
Assembly - ASR.Reports
Class - ASR.Reports.Items.QueryScanner

is there a way to add Sitecore.Mainutil or Sitecore.StringUtil in reference?
PS - i dont need c# code, need it using fast query or sitecore query

Comment: If you don't want to write any C# code then you may want to take a look at the [Sitecore Powershell Extensions module](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/reports.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to leverage `getLookupSourceItems` to perform a dynamic manipulation on the `source` value, but there isn't going to be a method to do this without "c# code". The query provider wasn't written with dynamic values in mind, unfortunately.

Which also leads me to the next point: If you find yourself falling short without this (and not to discredit the potential need for it), you may want to consider modifying your Infrastructure Architecture. There may be a (potentially) better way to sift through the information without involving some kind of token replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The report uses ASR.dll library. i wrote custom method to replace the string
Our report has an option to specify library file and the class to call. So wrote a custom class and replaced the string in c# code.